# Python Discord permissions value check

Tags: python, discord

How can I check if the Discord permissions value(e.g. 2147483647) has 0x2(kick user permission) in it?

Comment: If it's a bit field, then `if (2147483647 & 0x2):`

Comment: Thanks, it's working